# Execution of kcadm command on keycloak

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

i'm getting error when i'm executiong this commande :

```
kcadm create components -r master -s name=java-keystore -s providerId=java-keystore -s providerType=org.keycloak.keys.KeyProvider -s "config.priority=[\"101\"]" -s "config.enabled=[\"true\"]" -s "config.active=[\"true\"]" -s "config.keystore=[\"C:/Users/yamira/Documents/keycloakLicence/keystore.jks\"]" -s "config.keystorePassword=[\"secret\"]" -s "config.keyPassword=[\"secret\"]" -s "config.alias=[\"localhost\"]"
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

i'm getting this error on keycloak log side

`` 20:00:58,102 ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (default task-5) Uncaught server error: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Object>` out of VALUE_STRING token at [Source: (io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl); line: 1, column: 222] (through reference chain: org.keycloak.representations.idm.ComponentRepresentation["config"]->org.keycloak.common.util.MultivaluedHashMap["keystore"]) ``

Comment: Which Keycloak version are you using and which shell?

Comment: i'm using ver11.0.0  and with windows cmd

Comment: if i change `config.alias` to `config.keyAlias` this works for me

Comment: can you show me the full command plz

Comment: juste before executing the command i'm logged in as master with this command : kcadm config credentials --server localhost:8080/auth --realm master --user admin --password admin

Comment: with admin-cli client

Comment: This works for me on a command prompt on Windows 10 with Keycloak 11.0.0
`kcadm config credentials --realm=master --user=admin --server=http://localhost:8080/auth`

`kcadm create components -r master -s name=java-keystore -s providerId=java-keystore -s providerType=org.keycloak.keys.KeyProvider -s "config.priority=[\"101\"]" -s "config.enabled=[\"true\"]" -s "config.active=[\"true\"]" -s "config.keystore=[\"C:/Users/yamira/Documents/keycloakLicence/keystore.jks\"]" -s "config.keystorePassword=[\"secret\"]" -s "config.keyPassword=[\"secret\"]" -s "config.keyAlias=[\"localhost\"]"`

Comment: even me but i got that error ther's no special configuration or grant ?